# c++ templates in alpine build environments

Tags: c++, templates, libstdc++, alpine-linux

I am at a loss why such a non-type template argument construct

```
template <typename TValue, typename TFile, size_t PAGESIZE>
inline typename Size<Buffer<TValue, PageFrame<TFile, Fixed<PAGESIZE> > > >::Type
capacity(Buffer<TValue, PageFrame<TFile, Fixed<PAGESIZE> > > const &)
{
  return PAGESIZE;
}
```

would trip up clang(4.0.0) and g++(6.3.0) with Alpines buildbase/gcc/stdlibc++/cmake packages.
This happens in Alpine:

```
file_page.h:76:22: error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list
    template <size_t PAGESIZE>
                     ^
/usr/include/limits.h:44:18: note: expanded from macro 'PAGESIZE'
#define PAGESIZE PAGE_SIZE
                 ^
/usr/include/bits/limits.h:3:19: note: expanded from macro 'PAGE_SIZE'
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
                  ^
```

seems to me, macro expansion is very much intended here.
Any explanation is appreciated

Comment: Just to be sure, this works in other environments (e.g. ubuntu's build essentials etc.).

Comment: @user2296177 Too bad I am not really in control of that code as it is 3rd party code I am including. But any idea why that is working in other settings (like off-the-shelf ubuntu)?

Comment: Or the better question, why these defines are added in alpine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripped down, your code is similar to this:

```
#include <cstddef>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
#define PAGESIZE PAGE_SIZE

template<std::size_t PAGESIZE>
void f() {}
```

You are naming your non-type template parameter with the same name as a macro that expands to a certain value. It is as if you wrote:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t 4096>
void f() {}
```

This is clearly invalid syntax.

If you want to set a default value for the non-type template parameter to the value of your macro, you can write it like so:

```
#include <cstddef>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
#define PAGESIZE PAGE_SIZE

template<std::size_t page_size = PAGESIZE>
void f() {}
```

However, make sure to use `page_size` instead of the `PAGESIZE` macro inside your function.